# django SQL Error (1054, "Unknown column 'utility_voter.Id' in 'field list'")

Tags: python, django

Following are models In Model.py

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

# Create your models here.
class election_type(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type_of_election=models.CharField(max_length=200)

class party(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    symbol = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

class constituency(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    State=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total_voters=models.IntegerField()

class constituency_type(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    election_type_id=models.ForeignKey("election_type",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    constituency_id=models.ForeignKey("constituency",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)


class booth_manager(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    phone_no = PhoneNumberField(max_length=13,unique=True)
    aadhaar_no = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    constituency_id = models.ForeignKey("constituency",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    Reqired_FIELDS = ['name','phone_no','aadhaar_no','constituency_id']

class voter(models.Model):
    voter_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    aadhaar_no = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    phone_no = PhoneNumberField(max_length=13,unique=True)
    Reqired_FIELDS = ['name','phone_no','aadhaar_no','constituency_id']
    
class voter_constituency(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    voter_id=models.ForeignKey("voter",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    loksabha_id=models.IntegerField()
    vidhansabha_id=models.IntegerField()

class candidate(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_no=models.IntegerField()
    email= models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    aadhaar_no=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)

class candidate_party(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    candidate_id=models.ForeignKey("candidate",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    party_id=models.ForeignKey("party",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class candidate_constituency(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    candidate_id=models.ForeignKey("candidate",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    constituency_id=models.ForeignKey("constituency",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    election_type_id=models.ForeignKey("election_type",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class votes(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    candidate_id=models.ForeignKey("candidate",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    total_votes=models.IntegerField()


class voter_vote_status(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    voter_id=models.ForeignKey("voter",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    casted_vote=models.BooleanField(null=False)
```

Want to get details from voter model I'm getting this sql error when trying to get data in my view function.
Someone Please Help resolving this error is it caused to some fault in declaration of models or is there something else?
Even having executed: Python3 manage.py makemigrations utility,  and python3 manage.py migrate. I still get an error

Comment: Your app is named "utility", no? Is the exact comand you ran to make migrations `python3 manage.py makemigrations models`?

Comment: python3 manage.py makemigrations

Comment: Can you add the view that triggers the error and the full traceback to your question

Comment: Please add the error output